# A relationship is in the 'Deleted' state on updating

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

After read a lot of similary topics, I can't resolve this problem...

I have next model...

**Persons:** Id, Name, City

**Skills:** Id, Description, Person_Id

A person can have 0 o more skills, but a skill can have 1 person.

My form contains TextBoxs Name and City, and a GridControl bound with Person.Skills

In this GridControl y can delete, add or edit rows.

The problem is when I delete a row and save changes, i recieved next error:

"A relationship from the 'PersonsSkills' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state."

When I run method DbContext.Skills.Remove(skill) all work fine, but is this the best way? I have to do it manually for all rows deleted?

Code:

```
Private DbContext As New Model()
Private person As Person

'Load Person to edit
Private Sub loadPerson()
    Dim person As Person = (From p In DbContext.Persons
                            Where p.Id = IdPerson
                            Select p).First()
End Sub

NameTextBox.Text = person.Name
CityTextBox.Text = person.City
SkillsBindingSource.DataSource = person.Skills.ToList()


'Update changes
Private Sub save()
    person.Name = NameTextBox.Text
    person.City = CityTextBox.Text
    person.Skills = Ctype(SkillsBindingSource.DataSource, List(Of Skill))
End Sub
DbContext.SaveChanges()
```

Thanks for help!

PD: Sorry for my baaad english...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

When a row is deleted, I run:

```
DbContext.Skills.Remove(Ctype(SkillsDataBinding.Current, Skill))
```

After, in the "Save" procedure, set the navigation property like this:

```
person.Skills = Ctype(SkillsDataBinding.DataSource, List(Of Skill))
```

It was simple, but I'm a noob.